# Suddely Mogodb openssl stop connecting - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

using AWS linux 2023 , installed mongodb openssl.. it was working fine suddenly it start giving error

**Current Mongosh Log ID: 651a68e1bd5d207b9792aaad
Connecting to:          mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+2.0.1
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017**

on writing mongosh --version it is running successfully giving 2.0.1 verison exist

this is also error while checking status Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; preset: disab> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-10-02 10:24:00 UTC; 9s a> Duration: 1ms Process: 161134 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=e> Main PID: 161134 (code=exited, status=217/USER) C

i am just trying to connect using command mongosh.
nthing related to code. i am trying to connect using ssh .

Comment: on writing mongosh --version it is running successfully giving 2.0.1 verison exist

Comment: this is also error while checking status
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; preset: disab>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-10-02 10:24:00 UTC; 9s a>
   Duration: 1ms
    Process: 161134 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=e>
   Main PID: 161134 (code=exited, status=217/USER)
        C

Comment: Please put additional logging info as edit in the question, instead as a comment.